# Debian 10 Live USB 'loud beep' at boot

Tags: debian, boot, live-usb

I have a persistent Debian 10 USB that works completely fine, but when I select the USB in the boot menu a very loud 'beep-beep' plays, just before showing the 'GNU GRUB' menu I think it's called (looks like the photo below).

[image]

For what I've searched there are some questions already answered about removing this sound  mentioning a `^G` sign in a file which had to be removed.

I think this have changed in recent versions because I wasn't able to find the file containing that symbol. The file structure in my USB after burning the ISO is different and I think it doesn't contain the file mentioned. I've also searched in other locations as well but couldn't find anything.

How can I remove this sound? If the solution is deleting the `^G` sign, where can I find that file in Debian 10? Do I have to go to that file in my USB (as seen when opened in Windows OS) or do I have to boot in Debian to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to identify where the file `grub.cfg` is in the iso image (for me it is at `boot/grub/`). Remove the following two lines in the file:

```
insmode play
play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1
```

This is telling `grub` to play a tune of 440 Hz with a rest between it with a set tempo (refer to the grub manual for more detail). This is for booting from UEFI.

Remove the system bell `^G` in other files, for example, `isolinux/menu.cfg`, is for booting from the BIOS. I am guessing you are booting from UEFI but not BIOS, so removing `^G` doesn't work.